# How to create a javascript pagination for json array?

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to know how can i paginate a json array by using javascript?
Here is the json array which i need to paginate. this is a small array but i have to paginate a big array which hold 2000 records.

```
    {"Type":[["TF_OTHER","Other"],["TF_TRIP","Trip"],["TF_LUNCH","Lunch"]]}
```

Comment: How are you displaying the data?  If you are displaying as a table, jQuery Datatables is a great plugin for this: http://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this: (I didn't test it though)

```
<script>

var arr
function onLoad(jsonArr) {
    arr = eval(jsonArr);
}

function paginate(offset, max)
{
    var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
    for(var n=0; n<demo.childNodes.length; n++){
        demo.removeChild(demo.childNodes[0]);
    }

    for(var i=0; i<max; i++){
        var ele=document.createTextNode(arr[i+offset]);
        demo.appendChild(ele);
    }

    var next = document.getElementById('next');
    next.setAttribute("onclick","paginate("+(offset+max)+","+max+")");
    var pre = document.getElementById('pre');
    pre.setAttribute("onclick","paginate("+(offset-max)+","+max+")");
}

</script>
```